# Checking JSON empty array parameter on PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have decoded a JSON message using a PHP script. I would like to check if one of the parameters (which is a blank array *i.e.* `array()`) is blank but I cannot find the value to check it against in an `if` statement.

To clarify what I am referring to, here is an example in JSON format:

```
"contexts": [],
"metadata": {
  "intentId": "8c7c5399-7eba-41ea-bda7-42075813a922",
  "webhookUsed": "true",
  "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
  "isFallbackIntent": "false",
  "intentName": "broom1.off.time"
}
```

It is the `"contexts": []` value I would like to check against. In my PHP script I have the following code to do so:

```
if ($update["contexts"] == array()) {
    // do_something_here
}
```

*N.B.* `$update` has used the `json_decode` method to get the values of the JSON file. My question is, what is the value of that `contexts` paramenter?

Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php and `empty`.

Comment: The value is empty. There is nothing. I don't understand the question

Comment: But what you have should work https://3v4l.org/Q0Fk6 maybe better with `===`

Comment: What are you currently getting as the result? What makes you think that it is _not_ working?

Comment: use `json_decode(URL,true)` and then check if `empty($update['contexts')` is true

Comment: It is important to use `true` as the second parameter of json_decode()

Comment: It's working now, I'm using DialogFlow and it was being very temperamental... Thanks for all your help!